# Localstorage IE10 javascript FirstRun on ready code

Tags: javascript, local-storage, internet-explorer-10

This breaks in IE10 I think probably all IE versions not just 10, but trying to write windows apps can create some headaches.

```
var firstRun = (localStorage['firstRun'] == 'true');

if (!firstRun) {
  localStorage['firstRun'] = 'true';
  localStorage.money = 100;
}
```

I'm not sure if I can figure out how to rewrite this?

Comment: I think it's the line with "if (!firstRun) {" IE10 didn't understand.

Comment: Sorry, but it is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6vrUB/, in fact, the local storage feature is available just in IE8+

Comment: Thanks for testing this. I'll double check my code later.  It might be something kind of error before that than.  At least that's what the IE10 dev tools said which I tend not to trust.

Comment: In fact, you should trust. I just double checked using de dev tools, and it is working as well. Check if you are not misunderstanding the concept behind the local storage. Mainly confusing with the session storage option.

Comment: This ended up being a Windows8 issues not being able to run local javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose u are using file protocol. Dont use file URI scheme as local storage won't work in ie10 in this way. Install some server and access through localhost.